# Error Curl error 60: Cert verify failed: UNITYTLS_X509VERIFY_FLAG_USER_ERROR1

Tags: android, postgresql, unity-game-engine, hasura

I'm newbie Unity and Hasura. When i run project in Unity Editor, i create a query to Hasura, and it response List data. But when i build project to Android device, i have error is:

```
Curl error 60: Cert verify failed: UNITYTLS_X509VERIFY_FLAG_USER_ERROR1
```

and response data is:

```
{"errors":[{"extensions":{"code":"parse-failed","path":"$"},"message":"the key 'query' was not present"}]}
```

I don't know why happen, because Url endpoint of Hasura is Http not Https and database is Postgresql

I was change Url Endpoint of Hasura is Https to Http, try override RSA, and try disable SSL when request to Hasura